# Form to use AJAX rather than a page refresh but also utilise error handling?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a webform that I am about to integrate on my site.

http://app.bronto.com/public/webform/render_form/gmy3v1ej883x2lffibqv869a2e3j9/37ea72cebcc05140e157208f6435c81b/addcontact/

Firstly is the error handling. If you don't enter a name or valid email, validation messages appear on the page, but only after a page refresh.
Secondly, on submitting a valid (not empty) name and valid email address, it submits and redirects (redirect url site is currently offline).

My question is, how can I serialize the form to not refresh the page for both error message display AND submit? If submitted with no errors a message such as "You have been subscribed" should appear.

I have tried with `if data == success` for displaying the success message but no luck. I also can't seem to get the error messages displaying if it's not a success, which I presume is my issue with determining if there's an error or success.

In short, I'm trying to use ajax for the error messages and a success message on submit, without any refresh.

Any ideas on this one? Thanks

Comment: look at here http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Exactly what I did, looks good ;)

Comment: Read the FAQ -- this is a legit question. Leave it open.

Answer (score 2):

I think [jquery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) may suit you, it is used to submit form without any refresh, and is very famous. There many examples in its official website, it's really easy to use.

Hope helps ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use regex to validate the email in the javascript

```
<form action =" <action page>" method="<post/get>" id="frm1">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="Validate()" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

put this script in head section

```
<script>
function IsValidEmail(email) {
            var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            return expr.test(email);
        };
        function Validate() {
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            if (!IsValidEmail(email)) {
                alert("Invalid email address.");
            }
            else {
                alert("Valid email address.");
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: That will reject many valid email addresses. [Stop validating email addresses with regular expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/).

Comment: I have edited the code. now it will work

Comment: @DourHighArch i will add another code without regex

Comment: That still uses a regex and still does not work. `"Dour High Arch"+mailingGroup?12344@guggemheim.museum` is a valid email address.

Comment: @DourHighArch    Try this and check whether this regex has any problem

Comment: That doesn't even work on the example I've already given. Please read the article I posted; regular expressions do not validate email addresses.